# [__NSArrayI count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6dbfd10

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

I am using the Coreplot API to create a bar graph. When I try to run this same code as an individual project it's working fine but when I integrate it to my project inside `UINavigationController` it is giving me an error.

`GraphView.h`

```
    @interface GraphView : CPTGraphHostingView <CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>
   {
    CPTXYGraph *graph;
    NSArray *dates; 
   } 
  @property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dates;
```

`GraphView.m`

```
dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2012-05-01", @"2012-05-02", @"2012-05-03", 
             @"2012-05-04", @"2012-05-05", @"2012-05-06", @"2012-05-07", @"2012-05-08", @"2012-05-09",@"2012-05-10",@"2012-05-11",@"2012-05-12",@"2012-05-13",@"2012-05-14",@"2012-05-15",@"2012-05-16",@"2012-05-17",@"2012-05-18",@"2012-05-19",@"2012-05-20",nil];


 - (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return dates.count;
}
```

On return dates.count it is giving me the error.

> [__NSArrayI count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6dbfd10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating an autorelease object. Allocate memory to dates array.

```
dates =    [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2012-05-01", @"2012-05-02", @"2012-05-03", 
                 @"2012-05-04", @"2012-05-05", @"2012-05-06", @"2012-05-07", @"2012-05-08", @"2012-05-09",@"2012-05-10",@"2012-05-11",@"2012-05-12",@"2012-05-13",@"2012-05-14",@"2012-05-15",@"2012-05-16",@"2012-05-17",@"2012-05-18",@"2012-05-19",@"2012-05-20",nil];
```

Comment: Thanks parag it works. i have another issue CFDictionary allKeys]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6ce4dc0.. NSDictionay sets = sets =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [UIColor blueColor], @"Plot 1",
            [UIColor redColor], @"Plot 2",
            [UIColor greenColor], @"Plot 3", nil]

Comment: are you allocating memory for NSDictionary?

Comment: dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys will also create autorelase object. If you are using @property(nonatomic, retain) on NSDictionary then use self.sets = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blueColor], @"Plot 1", [UIColor redColor], @"Plot 2", [UIColor greenColor], @"Plot 3", nil]; else retain sets, sets = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blueColor], @"Plot 1", [UIColor redColor], @"Plot 2", [UIColor greenColor], @"Plot 3", nil]; [sets retain];

Comment: Better yet, use the new objc syntax.  Nice and clean `@[]` and `@{}`

Answer (score 2):

Drop the NSArray *dates instance variable - that's why you have the property, it makes that for you.

Then use the property setter:

```
self.dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2012-05-01", @"2012-05-02", @"2012-05-03", 
             @"2012-05-04", @"2012-05-05", @"2012-05-06", @"2012-05-07", @"2012-05-08", @"2012-05-09",@"2012-05-10",@"2012-05-11",@"2012-05-12",@"2012-05-13",@"2012-05-14",@"2012-05-15",@"2012-05-16",@"2012-05-17",@"2012-05-18",@"2012-05-19",@"2012-05-20",nil];
```